# Travel to other EU countries after resigning from my current Job while on Blue card Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas, immigration, resident-permit, blue-card

I have been living and working in Germany since April 2018 on Blue Card and recently renewed it as the previous one was only valid for 33 months. My new blue card is valid until Jan 2025.

I am currently working in Berlin and want to resign from my current job so that I can travel to some EU countries for 3 weeks.

Is it possible to travel after leaving my current job? After some research on the Internet I came to know that my Blue Card will be valid for 3 or 6 months after leaving my job, but can I travel during these 3 or 6 months?

Comment: What are your intentions **after** the 3 weeks travel? As long as you retain your residence (i.e. not deregistered) this will be considered a **temporary** absence. The residence permit will remain valid and can be used for visiting other Schengen Member states based on the 90/180 days rule.

Comment: After 3 weeks I would come back to Germany to live and work again. I just want to know if it's possible for someone to resign or leave current job and travel within the 3 months period?

Comment: Because after leaving a job you are supposed to find a new job in order to maintain a blue card but can you also travel to another eu countries without getting or finding a new job?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to directly contact the Ausländerbehörde responsible for your area of residence. (I have personally had good and straightforward responses from them in the past when I emailed them.)

That said, as long as your Blue Card remains valid (and you carry your valid passport just in case), I do not see why you cannot travel.

One thing I would double-check is the piece of paper they gave you with your Blue Card. Printed on it should be any conditions attached to your Blue Card. During the first 2 years, that paper should tell you that you have to notify them of any employment changes. Since your Blue Card status is over 2 years old now, you are probably free from that obligation.

This [link](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/migration/aufenthaltsrecht/aufenthaltsrecht-liste.html) contains some FAQs about residency permits, most of the information you probably already know. However, the last question contains some contact information of the Bundesamtes für Migration und Flüchtlinge (BAMF). You might also find direct answers from them, in addition to your local Ausländerbehörde.

As a last note, since you have over 33 months with your Blue Card, perhaps you might consider applying for a settlement permit, which may make things even easier.

Comment: Can you take a look here as well? https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/one-month-gap-between-changing-jobs-on-blue-card Thanks for the tip about contacting the responsible authorities. I will try that.